# Jquery fadeout callback firing too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

Try as I might I can't understand why this code...

```
function doVideoBanners () {

    // Set which banner we are fading out
    if ($('#youTubeBanner').length) {
        $theBannerToFade = $('#youTubeBanner');
    } else {
        $theBannerToFade = $('#revSliderBanner');
    }

    $('#find-h-banner-play').on('click', function() {

        // If code entry page, we don't need to scroll
        if (!$(this).hasClass('entry')) window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        $theBannerToFade.fadeOut('slow', function () {

            //////// Responsive YouTube iframe ////////
            var URL = 'xxxx';
            var videoIframe = '<iframe style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'"; width="1100" height="524" class="youTube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?rel=0;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allowtransparency></iframe>';

            // Because of elements jumping around, we need to set everything before we show the iframe
            $('.videoWrapper').html(videoIframe);

            // In the CSS videoWrapper is temporarily set to 524px
            $('.videoWrapper')
                .css('height', '0')
                .css('paddingBottom', '45.365%');

            $('.videoWrapper').removeClass('hidden');

        });

        // We don't want to restart the video should the user click it again
        $(this).off();
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');

    });
}
```

...doesn't fade the element THEN fire the callback. I've tried .promise() and     .done(). Any ideas, o' expert ones?

Comment: Try using a longer numeric time to debug easily

Comment: It only seems to happen when the scroll is invoked...

Comment: Is `.finish` or `.stop` being called on the element somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I put on 2 seconds but it just disappears really quickly (like's it's the default 400?).

Comment: @Stryner, I don't think so. The element is bespoke, created by me. This is the only code that affects it..

Comment: Could you put together a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or something so we can test out your exact code more easily?

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Just made a pen and the code is fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjJJyd. Must something up with how it works in Wordpress. Ho hum.

Comment: In the end @Stryner you were right, there was another stop() being called in a stray bit of code! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting `.delay()` on the function?

Comment: Doesn't help. I can see the delay happening then the fade just happens really quickly again.